# jQuery .hover method and function efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkubaStewart/5o54ur4q/1/)

I'm curious as to how the jQuery code could be cleaned up to be more efficient, if possible. I'm a novice JavaScript/jQuery coder (as one could tell), and being more of a visual person and interactive learner, I feel that this is paramount to learning the way(s) the languages are written.

In short, instead of duplicating the .hover method each time that I need .fadeIn to fade in a div could there be a way to create a variable that contains the entire function?

Here's the code:

```
$('.hover1').hover(function () {
    $('.reveal1').stop(true).fadeIn(400);
},

function () {
    $('.reveal1').stop(false).fadeOut();
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This is something that is easily handled using only CSS.

Comment: @k0pernikus It's not. Looks way too examplish to be [on-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @k0pernikus This will likely be considered 'example code' which is off-topic for CR. Next time, please don't use that kind of close reason. Being *possibly* on-topic on one site does not make it off-topic on another.

Answer (score 2):

You can amend your code using DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principles to shorten it.

Firstly, use common classes to group elements together, only putting `id` attributes on those which need unique settings:

```
<div class="links"> 
    <a class="hover" href="google.com">Link 1</a>
    <a class="hover" href="google.com">Link 2</a>
    <a class="hover" href="google.com">Link 3</a>
</div>

<div class="reveal" id="reveal1">test</div>
<div class="reveal" id="reveal2">test</div>
<div class="reveal" id="reveal3">test</div>
```

You can then simplify your CSS too, given these classes:

```
.reveal {
    display: none;
    background: url('http://www.gardenideas.com/images/content/lushLandscape.jpg');
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 35px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 25%;
    width: 25%;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#reveal1 {
    background-image: url('http://www.visual-arts-cork.com/images-paint/constable-haywain.jpg');
}
#reveal2 {
    background-image: url('http://www.gardenideas.com/images/content/lushLandscape.jpg');
}
#reveal3 {
    background-image: url('https://cdn.tutsplus.com/vector/uploads/legacy/tuts/13_Midnight_Grass/preview.jpg');
}
```

Finally, you can use a single click handler linked to those classes to do the work for you. You can join the `a` element to the relevant `.reveal` div via its `index()`:

```
$('.hover').hover(function () {
    $('.reveal').eq($(this).index()).stop(true).fadeIn(400);
}, function () {
    $('.reveal').eq($(this).index()).stop(false).fadeOut();
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5o54ur4q/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can store a function into a variable in JS

```
    var func1=function(){
        $('.reveal1').stop(true).fadeIn(400);
    };

    var func2=function(){
        $('.reveal1').stop(false).fadeOut();
    };

function provideHfunc(e)
{
$(a).hover(func1,func2);
}

  provideHfunc('.hover1'); // use this single function everywhere for the same functionality
```